# How to specify marker size as diameter in input space with plotly Scatter3d?

Tags: python, plotly, visualization, plotly-python, scatter3d

Experimenting with go.Scatter3d I noticed the option marker sizemode="diameter". It seems that this option is not related to the diameter of the markers in input space.

Is it possible to resize the marker with custom diameter in input space?

E.g. I want markers, each with a diameter of 5 in terms of the input space:

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

import numpy as np

x =y=z = np.arange(1,4)

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter3d(
        mode='markers',
        x=x,
        y=y,
        z=z,
        marker=dict(
            color=px.colors.qualitative.D3,
            size=5,
            sizemode='diameter'
        )
    )
)
axis_range = [-5,10]
fig.update_layout(scene = dict(
        xaxis = dict(range=axis_range,),
        yaxis = dict(range=axis_range,),
        zaxis = dict(range=axis_range,)
))

fig.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Dont' really understand your question, what you'd like to achive, but the docs: https://plot.ly/python/reference/#scatter3d are saying that the sizemode will only have an effect if `marker.size` is set to a numerical array.

[image]

So, based on your example:

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

import numpy as np

x =y=z = np.arange(1,4)

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter3d(
        mode='markers',
        x=x,
        y=y,
        z=z,
        marker=dict(
            color=px.colors.qualitative.D3,
            size=[5, 10, 30],
            sizemode='diameter'
        )
    )
)
axis_range = [-5,10]
fig.update_layout(scene = dict(
        xaxis = dict(range=axis_range,),
        yaxis = dict(range=axis_range,),
        zaxis = dict(range=axis_range,)
))

fig.show()
```

Comment: Thank you, I really missed this requirement.

To clarify my question: I'm trying to define the size of the markers at the scale of the input dimensions, but I guess that markers are not intended for that.